# Limit and skip options in MongoItemReader

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-batch

In my spring batch application I need to migrate data from mongoDB to postgreSQL.
I'm using [MongoItemReader](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/data/MongoItemReader.html) for reading data. This reader can be configured by setting several properties such as query, sort, fields, etc. But I don't want to read all data from collection, I want to read only part of it and get this part by 'skip' and 'limit' cursor properties. Is there any ability to do that via this class or I should use other mongo reader to solve my problem?

Here the code of my reader class which extends MongoItemReader.

```
public class MongoMigrateItemReader<T extends Migratable> extends MongoItemReader<T> implements ItemReader<T> {
    protected String collectionName;
    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public MongoMigrateItemReader() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Type type = ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) type;
        this.setTemplate(mongoTemplate);
        this.setTargetType(clazz);
        this.setCollection(collectionName);
        this.setQuery("{}");
        HashMap<String, Sort.Direction> sort = new HashMap<>();
        sort.put("_id", Sort.Direction.ASC);
        this.setSort(sort);
    }
```

}

I want to set limit and skip options in init() method

Comment: No code here. Show us what you are currently doing.

Comment: Are you using xml configuration or Java Config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MongoItemReader` utilizes paging as a mechanism for returning data instead of a cursor.  Since there is no cursor of the full dataset, using MongoDB's `cursor#skip` and `cursor#limit` are not an option.  To get what you'd want to do, you'd have to implement your own `MongoItemReader`.  That being said, we would appreciate a contribution if you feel it's useful for others!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guessed that MongoItemReader haven't got such mechanism. I needed this for making partition reading step. For example: first thread handles data from 0 to 1000, second from 1001 to 2000, etc. But I solved this by adding  property 'threadNum' to collection documents which calculated in partitioner  and then passed to slave steps where query criteria was changed to {threadNum : (value from stepExecutionContext)}.
But thank you again!

Comment: you can also avoid to add threadNum to the documents if you have some random value in it, like the id. If the id is a long, just divide it by totNumThread and take the remainder to find the threadNum. If it's a string, take its hashcode and do the same.

Comment: @GismoRanas Could you please provide the reference code snippet.
Tried with
<br/>
public MongoItemReader<Customer> reader(
   @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['offset']}") Integer offset,
   @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['pageSize']}") Integer pageSize
   ) {
  MongoItemReader<Customer> reader = new MongoItemReader<>();
  reader.setTemplate(mongoTemplate);
  reader.setCollection("myCollection");
  reader.setQuery("{}"); 
  reader.setPageSize(pageSize);
  reader.setCurrentItemCount(offset);
  reader.setTargetType(Customer.class);
  return reader;
 }

Comment: this is long ago, not using mongo anymore. but you can make a query with some where condition, for example "where _id % 13 == 5". this way you divide your data in 13 chunks or remainder classes from 0 to 12. if the _id is a string then transform it into an integer/long by using hashcode functions. you have to work out the details yourself, maybe ask another question.